# Information about minibeacon firmware

Tags: ibeacon, beacon, eddystone, google-beacon-platform

We develop applications using ble beacons. One of the beacons providers offering beacons with MiniBeacon firmware. I guess MiniBeacon firmware makes it possible to configure the beacon in iBeacon and Eddystone format simultaneously. Is it correct ?

I searched but could not find much information about MiniBeacon firmware. Does it have any known compatibility issues with Eddystone or iBeacon format or any known performance issues ?

Sorry for asking such a generic question. Thanks a lot. 
Reg,

Comment: It might help if you share a link to the source material about this firmware.

Comment: Hi David, here is the GitHub link posted by the firmware provider. It is a firmware developed by organization called RedBearLab.                                    https://github.com/RedBearLab/MiniBeacon

Comment: We are in fact using Android Beacon Library. So as a app developer, I am just wondering if the beacons having MiniBeacon firmware is compatible with ABL and if there are any known issues ? The positive side is, the firmware allows the beacon to be configured in iBeacon and Eddystone format simultaneously.  Thanks a lot. Reg...

Answer (score 0):

It does not look to me like the firmware supports Eddystone, at least not at the link referenced in the comment below the question.  That firmware is 3 or 4 years old by the changelog, dating to before the release of Eddystone.

The README mentions iBeacon compatibility, and if that format is indeed supported, it would be compatible with the Android Beacon Library if the library is configured with the proper BeaconParser for iBeacon.

You may wish to check with the firmware author to see if a newer version is available supporting Eddystone.

Comment: Thanks David. As per your advise, I will check with the beacon vendor about the support for iBeacon and Eddystone.